# Showing a limited number of mysqli_fetch_assoc array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create an array with the help of MYSQL and display it the following way:

```
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
echo $array["first_name"] . ", "
. $array["last_name"] . ", "
. $array["personal_id"] . ", "
. $array["salary"] . ", "
. $array["birthday"] . "<br />";
}
```

To improve usability, I only want to display 10 results, put a link to the next 10 results at the bottom and display these on another page.

How do I have to change the while-condition in order to only display the first 10 results of my result?

I tried searching for a solution but I couldn't find anything that fits my needs, so any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look for 'pagination with mysql and php'. Hundreds of examples out there.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks, sometimes it's hard for a non-native English speaker to find the right vocabulary that summarizes your problem :)

Comment: Also limiting the query would be more efficient rather than just adding pagination, because you'd fetch **EVERY** result everytime a user loads the page. Using both would be the best answer.

Comment: @sebjel That's why Jay gave you the right terms. It's not a criticism.

Comment: @tadman didn't take it as criticism, it's all good! Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check offset and limit conditions in mysql.
Example: to show 16 - 26 records from result query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15"
```

Comment: You need to add more substance to this to make it a full-fledged answer.

Comment: Answer Corrected :).

Comment: Much better. Bump that in four spaces to get the code-formatting to kick in and you're right on track.

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is just a way to break out of the loop after the first 10 results.

```
$counter = 1;
while (($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) || ($counter < 10))
{
    echo $array["first_name"] . ", "
    . $array["last_name"] . ", "
    . $array["personal_id"] . ", "
    . $array["salary"] . ", "
    . $array["birthday"] . "<br />";
    $counter++;
}
```